# XSLT Transforming multiple input to a single unbounded element

Tags: xslt-1.0

With my code we got a different requirement where we have to map multiple input to a single unbounded element. below are the example given.

Could someone please help on this.

**Source System XSD mapping**

```
<Errors>
<error>
<errorcode>code</errorcode>
<errortype>type</errortype>
<paramater1>error1</paramater1>
<paramater2>error2</paramater2>
<paramater3/>error3</paramater3>
<paramater4/>error4</paramater4>
<error>
<Errors>
```

where as now I have to map these values to **target xsd** which is of format like

```
<Errors>
<error>
<errorcode>code</errorcode>
<errortype>type</errortype>
<errorParameters>
  <errorPara>error1</errorPara>
  <errorPara>error2</errorPara>
  <errorPara>error3</errorPara>
  <errorPara>error4</errorPara>
</errorParameters>
</error>
</Errors>
```

here errorPara is a unbounded in nature which is inside the errorParameters element.

I am wondering how this can be achieved using XSLT 1.0

Comment: XSLT cannot select node by pattern / regular expression. If you have parameter1, parameter2, ... parameterN unbounded.... Besides errorcode, errortype, and parameter* is there any other child tag of error?

Comment: @KenCheung - Thanks for your response. No we do not have any child tag as unbounded in nature fr error.  do we have any inbuild function by using array or loop.. can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, only if error having only child of errorcode, errortype, and parameterN

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <!--Suppress unmatched text-->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <Errors><error>
        <errorcode><xsl:apply-templates select="Errors/error/errorcode"/></errorcode>
        <errortype><xsl:apply-templates select="Errors/error/errortype"/></errortype>
        <errorParameters>
            <xsl:for-each select="Errors/error/*">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="name() = 'errorcode'"></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="name() = 'errortype'"></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><errorPara><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></errorPara></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </errorParameters>
    </error></Errors>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="errorcode">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="errortype">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think the data xml on the question has some typo so I have change them:

```
<Errors>
<error>
<errorcode>code</errorcode>
<errortype>type</errortype>
<parameter1>error1</parameter1>
<parameter2>error2</parameter2>
<parameter3>error3</parameter3>
<parameter4>error4</parameter4>
</error>
</Errors>
```

Then the result (Linux: xsltproc test.xslt data.xml | xmllint --format -):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Errors>
  <error>
    <errorcode>code</errorcode>
    <errortype>type</errortype>
    <errorParameters>
      <errorPara>error1</errorPara>
      <errorPara>error2</errorPara>
      <errorPara>error3</errorPara>
      <errorPara>error4</errorPara>
    </errorParameters>
  </error>
</Errors>
```

Comment: I have tried this option but did not work in my case as we have other commplex logic in code. I raised the problem statement with a dummy XSD

Answer (score 0):

Here's one (simple) way to look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="error">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="errorcode | errortype"/>
        <errorParameters>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'paramater')]">
                <errorPara>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </errorPara>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </errorParameters>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there are no other children of error except `errorcode`, `errortype` and `parameterN`, you could use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::errorcode or self::errortype)]">
```